# What is the function of interrogative pronoun "qué" in "¿por *qué* está enfermo?"

Tags: gramática

Trying to determine the function of the interrogative pronoun "qué" in the sentence :

> ¿por qué está enfermo?

Stanford parsers says it is the "nominal modifier" of the adjective(?)/noun "enfermo".
Freeling pretends it is the "sn" of "Por", (couldn't find the meaning of "sn")

I also thaught about considering the whole group *Por qué* as being an "interrogative adverb", and its function as being the "root" of the sentence *¿por qué está enfermo?* **or** as being the "adverbial modifier" of *enfermo*

Can a passionate grammarian help out ?
Regards

Comment: Does https://www.rae.es/consultas/porque-porque-por-que-por-que help?

Answer (score 2):

I think "por qué" can be parsed as an interrogative adverb, especially when the answer is introduced by "porque":

- Está enfermo **porque** no se vacunó.

Alternatively, "qué" in "por qué" can be considered an interrogative pronoun functioning as the object to the preposition "por" and substituting for the cause (noun or infinitive) accounting for a certain situation.

- Está enfermo **por** no vacunarse / **por** falta de vacunación.

According to [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/por?m=form), "por qué" is said to be an adverb phrase ("locución adverbial"), but I find the term poor as it does not make any reference to its interrogative value, let alone to the possibility of breaking it down into two components.

Comment: Technically, it's called an "adverb phrase" ("locución adverbial"). Maybe you can improve your answer by adding [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/por?m=form) as source.

Comment: @Charo Thank you. I will, but I find the term vague.